# Java - ArrayList<> and LinkedList<> - class as an identifier

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, declaration

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTpVa.jpg

I don't get it what the identifier  does in this example, I'm new with programming and what I realize is that `ArrayList<String>` creates the list of Strings and same with `LinkedList<String>` but what happens when you push a class in the identifier, like - `LinkedList<Song>` - and `Song` is a class . Thanks in advance.

```
public class Main {
    private static ArrayList<Album> albums = new ArrayList<Album>();

    LinkedList<Song> playlist = new LinkedList<Song>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    // write your code here

        Album album = new Album("StormBringer" , "Deep Purple");
        album.addSong("Stormbringer" , 4.6);
        album.addSong("Love don't mean a thing" , 4.22);
```

Comment: String is a class just like Song

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html

Comment: Please add your code example as text and not as image. This makes it easier to read.

Comment: I've added some code , so String is a class just like Song and lets say ArrayList<Song> means that I've created a list of objects of class Song ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what happens when you push a `class` in the `identifier`?

First of all it's not an identifier it's a `Type`, and this is how [**Generics**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html) works, you pass a `Type` between `<>`, so the compiler knows the expected `Type` for this Generic class (here the Collection). And Collections `List`, `Set`... are good examples for [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/generics.html) implementations.

And like `Song` is a class **[`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)** is also a **predefined** class in the `java.lang` package, so when you pass a class to your collection, the compiler will expect that all the elements in this collection are of this `Type`.

For example in your code:

```
LinkedList<Song> playlist = new LinkedList<Song>();
```

All `playlist` items are expected to be instances of `Song` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

`String` is a class like `Song` is also a class. It means that you can only insert objects of this class into your `List`. Objects of other classes are not allowed to be added, because the type does not match. Trying to do so will result in a compile error. So your list is type save. This feature is called [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).